# Php connection to database: is it secure?

Tags: php, database, security

I use the following php code to connect to mysql database.

```
$hostname = "hostname.com";
$database = "dbtest";
$username = "admin";
$password = "pass123";
$connect = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database);
```

This code is placed in a connection file called connect.php which is included in all php scripts that require access to database.

If a hacker gets the url of connect.php (http://www.domainname.com/connect.php), is it possible to hack my database.
How can I ensure that the php connection code does not help the hacker? Or Which is the best secure way of connecting to the database?

Comment: If that is the only code in that file, it poses no danger whatsoever, unless the attacker is able to inject more code to be executed, or you have `.phps` enabled for viewing source code. If you are really worried, move that file outside documentroot. The `trigger_error()` instead of `die()` is nice to see, but make sure you don't show the error text to the user.

Comment: the script doesn't output anything, except the trigger_error that in shared hosting, doesn't output to user browser and usually is written to a file, so in the end the user that navigates to that URL will a get a white page.

Comment: Is your database server available to the world? Also, see Michael's much better answer in this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680808/how-to-invoke-a-php-file-that-is-located-outside-public-html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never ever have PHP files with code inside the document root of your website. The only thing in the document root should be a [bootstrap file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap#Software_bootstrapping) and route all requests through this. If you would have that file inside the document root of your site and for some reason the webserver doesn't parse the file it will be displayed as is.

And please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

And always use an ecrypted connection (SSL).

See this for [routing examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095932/routing-urls-in-php) and [dispatching patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115629/simplest-php-routing-framework). Basically what should happen is: all request are handled by the `index.php` file under document root. The `index.php` bootstraps everything (i.e. calls (includes)) another file outside of the document root. This file will check the URL of the request and finds out what file belongs to current URL and executes it.

Comment: /troll warning *what about wordpress*?

Comment: What about WP? Just don't use it... :-) @MichaelRobinson Have you seen the source. Oh the horror.

Comment: It is the prime example of how not to do ... anything.

Comment: In my opinion, I don't like the idea of `prepared statements`, I want to decide myself what my query looks like

Comment: @GeenHenk Because it is [the summer of love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/) I will not call you an idiot

Comment: Can a sample code be given for bootstap file and routing requests through it? I have no idea how this works.

Comment: @GeenHenk: then your opinion is wrong. :) Sorry, but prepared queries are pretty much security 101. Anything else is just asking for SQL injection vulnerabilities. There are plenty of places where differing opinions are great, but here, you are wrong, and you desperately need to change your mind, in much the same way as you'd be wrong if you said "In my opinion, I don't like the idea of driving in the same side of the road as everyone else", or "I don't like the idea of having to wash my hands before preparing food for my restaurant"

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this should be secure regarding your config data, if the hacker only has the URL to the file and if your webserver is configured properly so that the raw source code is not revealed.

You can increase security if you place such a config file outside the web root directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use `mysql_*` functions.
2. Put the file in some other place that under the directory for the document root for the web server.
3. Configure the web server to only allow connections from a list of IP addresses.
4. Consider using a secure connection (SSL) always and configure the database to only use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen if anyone accesses this page.

Though `mysql_*` on itself is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe.
You can also store the file outside DocumentRoot.